# Multicursor - not select all word in all lines?

Tags: multiple-cursors

Here is my text:

[image]

Now I want to select text after "**=**" and move it to beginning of word "`1111`"

```
M-x mark-sexp
```

And here is my result:

[image]

But I need to select the next words on 4 lines:

```
1111

aaaaaaaaaaaaa

11111

eeeeeddddd
```

How I can do this?

Comment: Are you running `mark-sexp` using `M-x`? If you are, multiple-cursors won't catch the command, since it only watches for keybindings, AFAIK. If you use `C-M-@`, which is the default keybinding for `mark-sexp`, or setup another keybinding, and it should work as expected.

Comment: @Jesse I don't known that multicursor only watches for keybindings. Now I know it. Thanks

Comment: @Jesse can you write an answer to this question based on your comment?

Answer (score 1):

If you are, multiple-cursors won't catch the command, since it only watches for keybindings
If you use "`C-=`"/"`C-M-@`" (**mark word**), which is the default keybinding for "`mark-sexp`", or setup another keybinding, and it should work as expected
     Attention!
     Multicursors work ONLY WITH KEYBINDING

I don't known that multicursor only watches for keybindings. Now I know it. Thanks

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13706)

Comment: @Stefan I updated my answer